# Sharing iPhone 4G data to router by Ethernet

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I would like to plug my iPhone into my router so data is shared, not connecting the devices directly to the iPhone wifi, but to the router.

Does anybody know if this is possible?
I see Ethernet-iPhone adapters for a few bucks, in Aliexpress for 4~10 USD
But I imagine (not sure why) that those would be mostly to connect the iPhone to a LAN, and **get** the data from there, not to provide the data service to others.

https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005004631900845.html
https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000492762600.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, connecting your iPhone to the router won't trigger the Personal Hotspot.

An iPhone will share its Internet connection only to devices connected through Wi-Fi, USB and Bluetooth (from [Share your internet connection from iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/share-your-internet-connection-iph45447ca6/ios)):

> You can use Wi-Fi, a USB cable, or Bluetooth to connect a Mac or PC to your Personal Hotspot. Do one of the following:
>
> - Use Wi-Fi to connect from a Mac
> - Use Wi-Fi to connect from a PC
> - Use USB: Connect iPhone and your computer with a cable.
> - Use Bluetooth

When you connect an iPhone to a router (or to a switch) using an Ethernet-to-Lightning adapter, the iPhone creates an Ethernet service, requests an IP address and uses that newly created Ethernet service to connect to the Internet.